# Angular form Control checkbox not stay checked after refresh

Tags: angular, typescript

My html file

```
<div class="row">

<div class="col-md-6">

<label for "legalentity">Governance Category</label> <div *ngFor "let governanceCategory of governanceCategories">

<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="{{governanceCategory)}" value="{{governanceCategory}}" name="governanceCategory" [checked]="selectedGovernanceCategories.includes(governanceCategory)" formControlName="governanceCategory"

(change) "changeClimateCategories(climateCategory)">

((governanceCategory}}

</div>

</div>
```

**.ts file**

```
changeGovernanceCategories(category) {

    let index = this.selectedGovernanceCategories.indexOf(category);

    if (index !== -1) {

      // Category is already in the array, remove it

      this.selectedGovernanceCategories.splice(index, 1);

    } else {

      // Category is not in the array, add it

      this.selectedGovernanceCategories.push(category);

    }
    this.form.controls['governanceCategory'].setValue(this.

selectedGovernanceCategories.sort().join("^"));
}
```

I tried removing the checked from input tag and I see all the checkboxes are getting selected if i select one of the check box. I need to utilise form to track and validate the page. I need some help on this

Comment: Do you mean after a page refresh? Do you persist the data anywhere?

Comment: Yes after refreshing the page the checkbox not stay checked. If I remove formControlname and name from the input tag it is working fine. But I want to track the changes so I added the formcontrolName and all the checkboxes are getting selected for the above code. If I change the formcontrolName to governanceCategories and removed the [checked] option from input tag then checkbox don't stay checked.

Comment: you can **not** use together [formControlName] and [checked]

Comment: Yes, even though I remove the [checked] and formControlname to governanceCategories. The checkbox is not get checked after a page refresh but it is storing the value

Comment: Do you save the changed data anywhere? If not, you can not keep the current state of the application on page refresh, it will be reset to what value you hardcode.

Comment: I didn't persist the data. That is what I want to know how to persist the data.